# SQL - CASE WHEN THEN truncates decimals

Tags: sql-server

The below sql query with CASE WHEN THEN returns different results. 
Note that the precision differs without the original query and with case 3 commented.
Any idea why? I am running SQL Server 2014.

```
declare @d1 decimal(20, 15), @d2 decimal(20, 15), @d3 decimal(20, 15), @d4 decimal(20, 15)
set @d1 = 22.0
set @d2 = 22.0
set @d3 = 1.00000
set @d4 = 7.0

select
    case when (1 > 0) then @d1 / @d4
        when (2 > 0) then @d2 / @d4
        when (3 > 0) then @d2 / (@d4 * @d3)
    end


--Results:
--Without case 3 commented: 3.142857
--With case 3 commented: 3.142857142857142857
```

Comment: Try using a float.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison: Float is not precise.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison The question is *Why does this happen?* And btw: `FLOAT` is - in most cases - something one should avoid...

Comment: Why did this get down votes?

Answer (score 3):

A `CASE` *expression* has to produce a result with a specific data type. That data type is determined when the `CASE` expression is compiled, and is derived from the data types of all `THEN` clauses and any `ELSE` clause.

The data type of your `case 3` expression has a lower scale than that of your other expressions, and so when it's included and all expressions are considered, you get the more limited scale in the result.

The exact rules for determining the data types of each of your `WHEN` expressions can be found in the documentation under [Precision, Scale and Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190476.aspx).

Comment: While the information in the MSDN Link _does_ help to answer the question, the information you have written here is misleading.  You write that Case-3 has the most limited Scale, and therefore this is why it is used.  This is false.  Given the same Integral Part, the Higher Scale will _always_ be used, however in this example, the computed Integral Part is different for Case-3.  In the OP's Example, Case-3's Scale is used because it resulted in both the Max Precision allowed (`38`) and the largest Integral Part (`38-6=32`): `decimal(38,6)`

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behaviour and has (almost) nothing to do with the `CASE-WHEN` construct: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx

> The operand expressions are denoted as expression e1, with precision p1 and scale s1, and expression e2, with precision p2 and scale s2. The precision and scale for any expression that is not decimal is the precision and scale defined for the data type of the expression.
>
> * The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

```
Operation       Result precision                     Result scale *
e1 + e2         max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1  max(s1, s2)
e1 - e2         max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1  max(s1, s2)
e1 * e2         p1 + p2 + 1                          s1 + s2
e1 / e2         p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)   max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
e1 UNION ** e2  max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2)      max(s1, s2)
e1 % e2         min(p1-s1, p2 -s2) + max( s1,s2 )    max(s1, s2)
```

** `e1 { UNION | EXCEPT | INTERSECT } e2`

Comment: The Excerpt from the MSDN Link that answers the question is this: "_The scale will be set to 6 if it is greater than 6 and if the integral part is greater than 32. In this case, both integral part and scale would be reduced and resulting type is decimal(38,6). Result might be rounded to 6 decimal places or the overflow error will be thrown if the integral part can't fit into 32 digits._"  When you Multiply the Precision and Scale are added, so by the time you do the Divide Operation (which will alter them further), they are too large, and thus your Scale is truncated to 6.

Answer (score 0):

you can use round funcrion:

```
select round(case when (1 > 0) then @d1 / @d4
    when (2 > 0) then @d2 / @d4
    when (3 > 0) then @d2 / (@d4 * @d3)
end,5)
```